# Android Studio y Bitbucket

Tags: android-studio, git, bitbucket

Resulta que hice algunas cosas mal en mi código de Android Studio y se me ha mezclado todo sin poder ordenarlo, en mi **repositorio** tengo una copia del código ordenado.

¿Como lo llevo a Android Studio? Por que si hago un `pull` me dice que esta actualizado.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Utilizas git o mercurial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Si el error se encuentra en el Repositorio Local.

No haz realizado `push` al codigo y los cambios mal logrados se encuentran de manera local.

#### Primera opcion

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Indicamos que retrocederemos un commit desde `HEAD` que en teoria debe ser el ultimo eliminando a su vez todo cambio realizado.

Este es un **metodo peligroso** ya que no hay ninguna forma para recuperar la copia original, los cambios se deshacen permanentemente. Debe tenerse cuidado al usarlo, ya que es uno de los únicos comandos [git](/questions/tagged/git) que tiene el potencial de perder tu trabajo.

> Se utiliza para deshacer los cambios en el área y el directorio de
>   trabajo **local**. En cualquier caso, debe ser utilizado para deshacer
>   los cambios locales, **nunca debe usarse en las instantáneas que han
>   sido compartidas con otros desarrolladores**.

#### Segunda opcion

```
git reset --soft HEAD
```

Indicamos que retrocederemos un commit desde `HEAD` que en teoria debe ser el ultimo sin embargo no perderemos los cambios realizados y estos se mantendrán como pendientes para versionar.

### Si el error se encuentra en el Repositorio Remoto.

Haz realizado `push` al codigo y se encuentra el error en el Repositorio Remoto (En linea).

#### Mejor opción

```
git revert HEAD
```

El error se encuentra a disposición de todos la mejor opción es deshacer el último commit.

### Diferencias

Revert y reset respectivamente.

[image: reset revert]

### Referencia

- [Atlassian -Undoing changes](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes)
- [Git- Deshaciendo cosas](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Fundamentos-de-Git-Deshaciendo-cosas)